# Bash Script that check if a database exist

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to create a bash script that check if a database(PostgreSQL) exists:

```
function is_database()
 return $(sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT exists(SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database where datname='\${1}')")

echo database:
read
is_database $REPLY
```

I always get(if exist or not the database):

```
exists ------ f (1 row)
```

The issue seems to be `'\${1}'` escaping doesn't work, and I already have outside `""`.

Other thing is to check the results, can be `f` or `t`.

Comment: I think that your read statement should be `read $REPLY` ... else $REPLY will always be empty.

Comment: if there is no variable to read by default is passed to $REPLY;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `return` only accepts a numerical result. When I change it to `echo` I get the same output as you.

Using `'\${1}'` will pass the string **${1}** to postgres, use `'${1}'` or `'$1'` (and hope that a user does not type some extra SQL to inject...)

Perhaps a different way without the need for `sudo` is to list the databases and grep the result:

```
function is_database() {
  psql -lqt | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -wq $1
}

echo database:
read
if is_database $REPLY
then
  echo $REPLY exists
else
  echo $REPLY does not exist
fi
```